# Autocomplete Closure Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have an issue with the close parameter of jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Essentially with the code in the close parameter, when the autocomplete is open, if i click a link the autocomplete dissapears but the link does not fire.

If i remove the code it works fine.

The JS runs through JS Lint fine and there is no console error.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
$('.mega-menu-search').autocomplete({
    source: window.searchTA.split(','),
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        megaMenuSearchAbort();
        megaMenuSearchTimeAndGo();
        lastSearch = $(this).val(); 
    },
    close: function(event, ui ) {
        // This is the troublesome code
        if($("#mega-menu-search-results").css("padding-top") !="0px") {
            $("#mega-menu-search-results").css("padding-top", "0px");
        }
    }
}).autocomplete("widget").addClass("mega-menu-autocomplete");
```

Comment: If you want to set the `padding-top` to zero if it is _not_ zero – then why do you encapsulate that into an `if`, instead of just setting it to zero no matter what? (Have you actually checked the value you are getting back from `$("#mega-menu-search-results").css("padding-top")` if it actually _is_ exactly the string `"0px"`?)

Comment: Very good point, this was a hangover from some older code i had. If i remove the if statement the problem does however still persist.

Comment: What do you mean by _“the link does not fire”_?

Comment: The link does not go anywhere, all that happens is the autocomplete popup dissapears. If you then click it again it works. When you however over the link you get a pointer and the url is shown in the bottom left of the browser so its a clickable element for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got a fix.

I am guessing that autocomplete must return false or stop propagation after running whatever function is in the close parameter.

In the code below i have removed the surplus if statement that was in my original code, although even with it left in, this fix works.

```
$('.mega-menu-search').autocomplete({
    source: window.searchTA.split(','),
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        megaMenuSearchAbort();
        megaMenuSearchTimeAndGo();
        lastSearch = $(this).val(); 
    },
    close: function(event, ui ) {

        // Changed code
        if(e.target.nodeName != 'A') {
            $("#mega-menu-search-results").css("padding-top", "0px");
        }
        //

    }
}).autocomplete("widget").addClass("mega-menu-autocomplete");
```

Comment: I should add this works my stopping the event occuring, if a link is clicked. This fixes my specific scenario, You would have to extend if you wanted to do something else.